# Godot shooting left and right

Tags: godot

how can i shoot both side the left and the right??

player

```
    func get_input():
    velocity = Vector2()
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right"):
        velocity.x += 1
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
        $AnimatedSprite.play("run")
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x -= 1
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
        $AnimatedSprite.play("run")
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_down"):
        velocity.y += 1
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
        $AnimatedSprite.play("vetical")
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        velocity.y -= 1
        $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
        $AnimatedSprite.play("vetical")
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        
        shoot()
        #AnimatedSprite.play("stop")
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed

        
func _physics_process(delta):
    get_input()
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)


func shoot():
    var b = Bullet.instance()
    get_parent().add_child(b)
    b.transform = $Gun.global_transform
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code you've shared here? How does it differ from what you want? Being precise about these details helps you get accurate answers, faster.

Comment: when i run the code it only shoot on the right side but when i shoot in the left side the bullet just fire only on the right side

Comment: also when i fire my player it just automatically move on the left side

Comment: Your Bullet needs a velocity, doesn't it? How does the Bullet know how to move? You give it position by setting the transform (I believe you should set the global transform, but that's the point), but I don't see you give it velocity.